# How to check if a value exists in a session

Tags: php

I want to check if the value `$row['id']` exists in the session, and if it exists to make the input become checked. I tried to make it like my code below but it doesn't work and it fails my select from the database with "Array to string conversion" error.

```
echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="scheck[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"';
if(isset($_SESSION['SELECT_SIZE_PRODUCTS'])) {
$_SESSION['SELECT_SIZE_PRODUCTS'] = array();
if(is_array($_SESSION['SELECT_SIZE_PRODUCTS']) && in_array($row['id'], $_SESSION['SELECT_SIZE_PRODUCTS'])) {
    echo ' checked="checked"';
}
}
echo ' /> '.$row['size'].'</li>';
```